Having trouble fixing Leaflet-React v4 & Nextjs 14.2.5 compatebility issue
Currently my map has completely broken the rest of my code and won't render anything to the page. Its met with a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')", but no where in my code do I use this component.
This is my package.json for reference (note that there are other parts to my project but I've mainly just changed the leaflet parts and some jest tests):
 "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.1.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility": "^0.1.2",
    "lucide-react": "^0.334.0",
    "next": "^14.2.5",
    "nx": "^19.1.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.4",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "zod": "^3.22.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.6.17",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.6.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.6.17",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.11",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.6.17",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.6.17",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.6.17",
    "@storybook/test": "^7.6.17",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.3.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.12",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-leaflet": "^3.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^6.2.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.11",
    "storybook": "^8.1.10",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.4",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
 
//and the map.tsx:

interface MyMapProps {
  position: LatLngExpression;
  zoom: number;
}

const Map: React.FC<MyMapProps> = ({ position, zoom }) => {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={position} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default Map;

